# A long time ago I asked a question that was not answered. Should I close it?

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[How can I keep the tooltip active on apexcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704388/how-to-keep-the-tooltip-active-on-apexcharts)*

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be closed?

Comment: I did not find the solution to the problem until today, but i think it can be more time here, thanks!

Comment: If you've found the solution, then you should post it as an answer to your question!

Comment: You have to ask yourself WHY it was never answered. It is a very limited question, only a few words of explanation and a tiny snippet of code which does not really make it clear why it would solve anything related to what you want to achieve. Surely you can explain it a little better than that.